# Left adjoint pseudofunctor commutes with pseudocolimits

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, adjoint-functors

I'm looking for a reference for this seemingly basic fact: assume I have a 2-functor $G : {\cal X}\to {\cal Y}$ and assume I can define a left 2-adjoint $F$ for it, which is nevertheless only a pseudofunctor.

> Is it true that $F$ commutes with all pseudocolimits in $\cal Y$?

Comment: I'm looking forward to seeing an answer to this question. My idea would be to take the proof that left adjoint functors commute with colimits and then sprinkle "up to isomorphism" generously throughout the proof. But I'd like to be shown how to do the sprinkling correctly and what more, if anything, is needed for a real proof.

Comment: I think it should commute with all weighted 2-colimits. I think you use the pseudo-adjunction's equivalence on the Hom-objects, then use the definition by representability of weighted colimits to flip the weighted colimit out to a weighted limit of hom-objects, then apply the inverse equivalence objectwise, then flip the weighted limit back inside to a weighted colimit using the definition of representability again, which is also an equivalence.

Comment: I guess the subtle part is showing the last step, since it's not obvious to show that the weighted colimit will exist in Y.  If you assume Y is cocomplete with respect to diagrams of the original shape and weight, then it's clear, I think.

Comment: Oh, wait, it's obvious anyhow by definition of (pseudo)representability for weighted 2-colimits.  I don't think that there is anything subtle at all, it should just be the same as the usual proof but replacing the isomorphisms with equivalences.

Answer (score 3):

> My idea would be to take the proof that left adjoint functors commute with colimits and then sprinkle "up to isomorphism" generously throughout the proof.

The usual argument seems indeed to apply here, but there are a few details I am not convinced with, and I would like to understand the proof with a certain command.

- First of all the definition of pseudocolimit I'm using: if $W : {\cal A}° \to\bf Cat$ and $D : {\cal A}\to \cal B$ a pseudocolimit $W\boxtimes D$ of $D$ weighted by $W$ is an object of $\cal B$ such that there is an isomorphism of categories
  $$
  {\cal B}(W\boxtimes D,B)\cong \text{Psd}({\cal A}°,{\bf Cat})(W, {\cal B}(D,X))
  $$ My first question is: shall I assume that this isomorphism is only an equivalence?
- A rather nontrivial result now gives me that there is a (possibly ultra-complicated) weight $\bar W$ such that $W\boxtimes D$ is in fact an honest $\bar W$-weighted colimit. Is this true without further assumptions on the data?
- If yes, the proof now boils down to the classical argument "sprinkled" with some canonical isos, since the hom-functor still commutes with ($\bar W$-)weighted colimits (I can assume $\cal B$ is co/tensored, this is not 
  a problem), and then
  $$
  \begin{array}{c}
  F(W\boxtimes D) \xrightarrow{\qquad \qquad} B\\\hline
  W\boxtimes D \xrightarrow{\qquad \qquad} GB\\\hline
  \{\!\!\{W,(D \xrightarrow{\qquad \qquad} GB)\}\!\!\}\\\hline
  \{\!\!\{W,(FD \xrightarrow{\qquad \qquad} B)\}\!\!\}\\\hline
  W\boxtimes FD \xrightarrow{\qquad \qquad} B
  \end{array}
  $$ (braces = weighted *limit*).

Comment: In traditional 2-categorical terminology, if your displayed isomorphism is an isomorphism you have a "pseudocolimit" whereas if it is only an equivalence then you have a "bicolimit".  And the replacement of pseudocolimits by strict colimits with a different weight is always true; but I'm not sure why you would be using that, since a pseudo-adjunction is not going to preserve strict colimits *strictly* anyway, or pseudocolimits for that matter, though it should preserve bicolimits.

Comment: Thank you. What would a precise statement about colimit preservation under a pseudofunctor be, then? (as you can see, I am confused by where to put the weakness)

Comment: In the most traditional 2-categorical terminology, it would be "a left biadjoint homomorphism of bicategories preserves bicolimits".  Fortunately most modern authors say "functor (of bicategories)" or "pseudofunctor" instead of "homomorphism of bicategories".  And some say simply "adjoint" and "colimit" instead of "biadjoint" and "bicolimit" when the context makes clear we are talking about bicategories, for which no stricter notion really makes sense.  The nLab often says "2-adjoint" and "2-colimit" for these weak ones, although in traditional 2-categorical terminology "2-" means strict.

Comment: Have you ever thought about TeXing a two-page document that explains the terminology once and for all? I mean, we should do something, write a IUPAC (= *I*nternational *U*nion of *P*ure and *A*pplied *C*ategorytheorists) nomenclature, a periodic table (even though the name is already taken), a *Systema Functores*...

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-category#Weak, https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pseudofunctor, https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-adjunction, https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-limit#Terminology